# SUMPRODUCT with empty cells / ISNUMBER

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A               B                c            D
1   Products           Sales 
2   Product A            50          Product A       #VALUE!
3   Product A            60          Product B
4   Product A            20          Product C
5   Product B            90
6   Product C            80
7   Product C            50
8   =""                =""
```

In **Column A** is a list of products and their corresponding sales are listed in **Column B**. In **Column D** I want to show the sum of the sales by using the following formula:

```
D2 = SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8)*($A$2:$A$8=C2))
```

Instead of showing me the result of 130 *(B2+B3+B4)* I get an #VALUE! error which is caused by the =" " in **Row 8**.

How can I make this formula work despite the =" " in Row 8.

I tried to go with this way but it still shows an error:

```
D2 = SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B$8)*($A$2:$A$8=C2)*ISNUMBER($A$2:$A$8)*ISNUMBER($B$2:$B$8))
```

Please keep the following in mind: I cannot switch the SUMPRODUCT formula to a SUMIF(S) formula since my original file is more complex then the simple example above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'native' form (i.e. with comma-separated arguments) of `SUMPRODUCT`, rather than the 'product' form, since text entries passed to the former are ignored.

`=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8,0+($A$2:$A$8=C2))`

I am slightly concerned about your statement "*I cannot switch the SUMPRODUCT formula to a SUMIF(S) formula since my original file is more complex then the simple example above.*". If the example you gave is not representative of your actual set-up, then it may be that a switch to the 'native' form of `SUMPRODUCT` is not actually possible (one advantage of the 'product' form is that it allows the processing of two-dimensional arrays, something which is not permissible within the 'native' form.)

Regards

Comment: Hi XOR LX, thanks for your answer. I see your point but when I try your formula in my complex original file it does not work. I simplified the example above to make it easier to understand my question. However, I will wait a bit and if there is no answer I might ask the question with my complex data again.

Comment: So in your actual formula are any of the arrays being passed to SUMPRODUCT of more than one dimension? And why can't you give a formula which is identical to that you are actually using (confidential data replaced with dummy data if necessary)?

Comment: Hi XOR LX, you can find the more complex data base in the following question I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44514606/sumproduct-with-multiple-criterias-and-empty-cells