# SUMPRODUCT with multiple criterias and empty cells

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B               C         D        E        F         G
1               Profit           1.Sales  2.Sale   3.sale      
2   Product A     50              500       600       0      Product A   110
3   Product A     60                0       400       0      Product B   90  
4   Prodcut A     20                0         0       0      Product C   130
5   Product B     90              800         0       500
6   Product C     80                0         0       400
7   Product C     50              300       750       200
8   =""           =""             =""        =""       =""
```

In **Column A** different products are listed. *It can happen that the same products appear several times in the list.* In **Column B** you can find the budgeted profit for each product and in **Columns C:E** the different sales of each product.

In **Column G** the sum of the profit of each product is shown in case the product has any sales. For example **Product A** has no sale in **Row 4**; therefore the sum of its profit is **B2+B3 = 110**.

I use the following formula to get the sum of the profit:

```
G2 = SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$7*(($C$2:$C$7>0)+($D$2:$D$7>0)+($E$2:$E$7>0)>0)*($A$2:$A$7=F2))
```

This formula works perfectly so far.

However, now I want to expand this formula to **Row 8**.
Row 8 does include **=" "** which causes a result of #VALUE! of the above formula.

How can I make this formula work despite the **=" "** in **Row 8**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()` with two arguments:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$8,(($C$2:$C$8>0)+($D$2:$D$8>0)+($E$2:$E$8>0)>0)*($A$2:$A$8=F2))
```

[image]